# How to give only "Add content" access permission for a particular users in drupal 7?

Tags: php

Please help me for this question(How to give only "Add content" access permission for a particular users in drupal 7 ?)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new User Role and give Add Content permission to that Role. Then assign particular user to that role. Now that user can able to add content only.

**Steps**:

Go to **administration -> people**

Click **Permission** tab.

Give Role name like **"Editor"** and click **Add Role**

After Creation, click **Edit Permission** against new created role and give the required permissions.